# Using shingles to flatten concrete subfloor

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, subfloor, engineered-flooring

I am installing (floating) 3/8" engineered hardwood over a concrete subfloor with 1/8" underlayment.  After grinding high spots and filling in larger voids with self-leveler, I have occasional 1/8" or less dips that I have come across while laying the floor.  I have read [here](https://www.askthebuilder.com/getting-a-new-hardwood-floor-level/) and elsewhere that roofing shingles can be used on a wood subfloor to raise small valleys.

- Can shingles be used on a concrete subfloor too?
- What are the concerns with using them on concrete if an adhesive like Liquid Nails is used to secure them in place?

Comment: Roofing shingles seem very thick to me.  What type of shingle are you referring to, exactly?

Comment: I guess I'm not a shingle expert (or any kind of expert when it comes to what I'm trying to do!).  I think just *normal* (non-architectrual) asphalt shingles.

Comment: Hmm, yea I looked at your link that that seems to be talking mostly about wood subfloors where I could see bigger gaps happening.  A new asphalt shingle can probably get closer to 3/16".  Maybe a very cheap shingle would be 1/8", but even then you would have to buy a whole bundle.  Can you just use a feather-edge concrete patch?

Comment: "The subfloor doesn't have to be absolutely in the same plane to prevent squeaks, but voids of **1/8 inch or more** can cause problems." - you have **1/8" or less**.... Party on, Dude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done things like this on a number of occasions, and the problem is that you'll create more bumps than you resolve. Only the inner portion of your depressions measures 1/8", and fairly quickly they taper up to a smaller dimension. This means that the edges of your shingles are almost always too thick for their position.

Also, they're crunchy. For at least a while after installation you'll hear it underfoot.

You're much better off skimming with a leveling compound.

Comment: Would not recommend construction adhesive or anything that attaches or has the potential to attach the floor to the sub floor as this is a "floating" floor and any place that is attached can be a point at which the floor buckles in the future because it cannot move. On a floating floor an 1/8 inch isn't even going to be noticeable as the sound deadening foam on some of these floating floors is that thickness.

Comment: That's a fair point. When I wrote this answer I was thinking wood subfloor for some reason.

Comment: The link:  "But shingles can be hard to work with and they **don't fill the entire hollow spot**." If it's less than an 1/8" nothing will fit there, and nothing needs to. If they're that bad the voids should have been feathered, same as the high spots were.